# JSON 2D Object Read Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have json like this:

```
balancer:"[
   "2", {"balancer_upload": 0, 
         "balancer_upload_speed": -120,
         "balancer_download": 0, 
         "balancer_download_speed": -120},
   "3", {"balancer_upload": 12, 
         "balancer_upload_speed": -90,
         "balancer_download": 8, 
         "balancer_download_speed": -20}]";
```

How can i get in javascript values:

```
 first id ==> 2 and values from balancer_upload, balancer_upload_speed, balancer_download, balancer_download_speed
```

I try using foreach but is not working...

UPDATE QUESTION:

Full JSON Format:

```
{"total_users":1,"expired_users":4,"free_test":0,"pay_test":0,"total_devices":6,"online_devices":0,"android_devices":0,"enigma_devices":0,"mag_devices":0,"main_upload":0.07,"main_upload_speed":-120,"main_download":3.16,"main_download_speed":-120,"balancer":"[\"2\", {\"balancer_upload\": 0, \"balancer_upload_speed\": -120, \"balancer_download\": 0, \"balancer_download_speed\": -120},\"3\", {\"balancer_upload\": 0, \"balancer_upload_speed\": -120, \"balancer_download\": 0, \"balancer_download_speed\": -120},\"4\", {\"balancer_upload\": 0, \"balancer_upload_speed\": -120, \"balancer_download\": 0, \"balancer_download_speed\": -120},\"5\", {\"balancer_upload\": 0, \"balancer_upload_speed\": -120, \"balancer_download\": 0, \"balancer_download_speed\": -120}]"}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: this is valid json i cut beginning and ending others json elements because its single json...i need to get elements only from this above example

Comment: No, it's not valid, literally because you cut out parts that do make it valid. You should fix up your code; sometimes copy/pasting isn't good enough. -- the quotation marks that you have is what's making it not valid

Comment: ok i updated question with full json code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That object isn't a 2d array? its a mixed type array.

I would suggest a clean up of the data before using it.

```
var balancer = [
 "2", {"balancer_upload": 0, 
       "balancer_upload_speed": -120,
       "balancer_download": 0, 
       "balancer_download_speed": -120},
 "3", {"balancer_upload": 12, 
       "balancer_upload_speed": -90,
       "balancer_download": 8, 
       "balancer_download_speed": -20} ] ;

for( var t = 0; t < balancer.length; t+=2 ) {
   var id = balancer[t]; 
   var values = balancer[t+1]; 
   // do stuff. 
}
```

*edit*

Your balancer is a string you need to parse the json like as mentioned before.

```
var myObj = {
  "total_users": 1,
  "expired_users": 4,
  "free_test": 0,
  "pay_test": 0,
  "total_devices": 6,
  "online_devices": 0,
  "android_devices": 0,
  "enigma_devices": 0,
  "mag_devices": 0,
  "main_upload": 0.07,
  "main_upload_speed": -120,
  "main_download": 3.16,
  "main_download_speed": -120,
  "balancer": "[\"2\", {\"balancer_upload\": 0, \"balancer_upload_speed\": -120, \"balancer_download\": 0, \"balancer_download_speed\": -120},\"3\", {\"balancer_upload\": 0, \"balancer_upload_speed\": -120, \"balancer_download\": 0, \"balancer_download_speed\": -120},\"4\", {\"balancer_upload\": 0, \"balancer_upload_speed\": -120, \"balancer_download\": 0, \"balancer_download_speed\": -120},\"5\", {\"balancer_upload\": 0, \"balancer_upload_speed\": -120, \"balancer_download\": 0, \"balancer_download_speed\": -120}]"
}

var balancer = JSON.parse(myObj.balancer);
```

Comment: I updated question above with full json format...sorry for not posting full json code...this code above works for first example..but for full json does not..could you please rewrite it?